# write a sql Query to fetch records with multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, mainframe

I have a table with Roll Number, name. But for some of the roll numbers, there are records with different names

In the

[image]

table, Roll numbers 2 and 6 have multiple records with the same roll number but different names.

I need to write a query/cursor to fetch such records from the above table Student.

Eg: Table - Student

```
|Roll No.| Name |
| -------| -----|
| 1      | A    |
| 1      | A    |
| 2      | B    |
| 2      | C    |
| 2      | D    |
| 3      | E    |
| 3      | E    |
| 4      | F    |
| 5      | G    |
| 6      | H    |
| 6      | I    |
```

The expected output should be 2, 6(Roll numbers having multiple records but with different names)

Number 1, 3 should not in the expected result because they have same name in all the records

Comment: *to fetch such records from the above table* Do you need problematic `Roll No.` value only, this value with CSV `Name`s list , complete rows arrays for such values, unique rows array? Show desired output for shown data.

Comment: So, what keeps you from writing the query? What is your question?

Comment: Again, what is the problem you are facing with writing this query? Then, the desired output is still not at all clear. "fetch such records" means three rows for roll number 2 and two for roll number 6. But "The expected output should be 2, 6" suggests you only want two result rows. And with one single column at that (the roll number). Or do you even want one row with a mere string containing the roll numbers comma-separated? So, again: Please show the expected result. In a table, just like you have shown the original table data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can do next query:

```
select roll_no
from Student
group by roll_no
having count(distinct name) > 1;
```

[MySQL group by](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=3afd039bff7a17acd89d78640a197b99&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Result:

```
+=========+
| roll_no |
+=========+
| 2       |
+---------+
| 6       |
+---------+
```